# how to set $HOME variable so that cmd find the path

Tags: windows-10, command-line, environment-variables

Regardless of what directory I am at, for instance, when type in `cd ~/Documents/project` in git bash, it works. Whereas, it will not work doing the same in the cmd. It says: the system cannot find the path specified.

I have searched for how to get the $Home variable in the cmd to work but there are many different answers and all of them quite old. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

If your "HOME" environment variable is not set (or if you don't know what this is):

1. Open command prompt (Open Start Menu, then type cmd and press [Enter]) Type the following line into the command prompt window exactly as shown:

   setx HOME "%USERPROFILE%"
2. Press [Enter], you should see "SUCCESS: Specified value was saved."

Answer (score 2):

#### Doing the same in the cmd. It says: the system cannot find the path specified.

> cd ~/Documents/project

`cmd` does not understand [`~` expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) as it is not `bash` compatible.

`cmd` also does not use `$HOME`. Instead it uses `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%`

You can set a new environment variable %HOME% as appropriate for your needs and then use:

```
cd %HOME%
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.
- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [Bash Reference Manual: Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)
- http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them